# Is there a method can convert a BOOL into NSString in objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

Is there a method can convert a BOOL into NSString in objective-C?

for example:

```
BOOL a = YES;
NSLog(@"a is %i",a);
```

but the output is "a is 1", I want it to print YES.

Comment: It is a tad silly that there's no, eg, `%b` formatting code for BOOL, but Jeow's scheme is what I usually use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the conditional operator to return string from the boolean.

```
BOOL a = YES;
NSLog(@"a is %@", a ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

Comment: semantics: that is the "conditional operator", which happens to *be a* "ternary operator", in the same way that `&&` is a "binary operator".

Comment: Minor point.  You can save a few chars with `NSLog(@"a is %s", a ? "YES" : "NO");`

Comment: @HotLicks: But you probably meant %s, not %c :-)

Comment: @MartinR - You are correct, sir!!  Stupid goof.  (Edited to use %s.)

Comment: You could save even more chars by using the preprocessor to stringify the boolean literals.